# data not getting stored in the data base LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

working on register page in laravel and i am trying to store the giving values to the users table in the database, but it doesn't work and i am not getting any errors and i tried everything .

the blade :

```
<section class="primary-bg">
<div class="container">
    <div id="login_signup">
        <div class="form_wrap_m">
            <div class="white_box">
                <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                <form action="{{ route('store')}}" method="post">
              @csrf
              
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ce champ doit être rempli')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ce champ doit être rempli')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ce champ doit être rempli')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ce champ doit être rempli')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block" value="Register Now">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Sign In</a></p>
                <div class="back_home"><a href="/" class="btn outline-btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> accueil</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller :

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'
        ]);

      $user = new User;

      $user->name = $request->prenom;
      $user->last_name = $request->nom;
      $user->email = $request->email;
      $user->phone = $request->telephone;
      $user->password = $request->password;

      $user->save();

      return redirect('/');

}
```

and this is the route :

```
Route::post('/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@store')->name('store');
```

i added the inputs to the user model as you can see :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nom',
    'email',
    'password',
    'prenom',
    'telephone',
];
```

and i am calling the controller in the web.php .
i have done everything correctly i guess .. but nothing happens when i submit, it's like the route is not working or something .

Comment: As i can see you are validation not existing fields like `last_name`, `phone`. These fields not existing in your front-end form.
Please check again, maybe you getting validation error.

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan no i am not getting any errors

Comment: @MatlayaDMonaim try my code, it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

1 - add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` to your controller

2 - first you should validate the correct fields that come from the form.

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
     $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'prenom' => 'required',
        'nom' => 'required',
        'telephone' => 'required|regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'

        ]);
     if ($validator->fails()) {
         return array(
              'fail' => true,
              'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
          );
     }
     else {
      $user = new User();

      $user->name = $request->get('prenom');
      $user->last_name = $request->get('nom');
      $user->email = $request->get('email');
      $user->phone = $request->get('telephone');
      $user->password = $request->get('password');

      $user->save();

  return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

3 - you should declare your database table column name in fillable not form fields.

```
protected $fillable = [
'name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'password'
];
```

4 - if work with laravel 8, you should validate `telephone` like this:

```
'telephone' => array(
  'required',
  'regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/',
  'digits:10'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your validation
, you have to validate the request input not the user table columns

```
  $request->validate([
                'prenom' => 'required',
                'nom' => 'required',
                'telephone' => 'required|regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'
                    ]);
```

not this

```
  $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'
        ]);
```

and you have to put  your columns names not the request names here

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'last_name',
    'password',
    'email',
    'phone',
];
```

and you can use

```
User::create(['name' => $request->prenom,
                'last_name' => $request->nom,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phone' => $request->telephone,
                'password' => $request->password])
```

for more information about storing the data

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: @AL.Sharie didn't work ... i guess there something wrong with the route maybe because when i try to insert string directly into the table using the store function without the inputs it doesn't work